# Crystal Reports - formatting the output

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working with Crystal reports 12. My command returns the results as follows 
(Sorry for using text delimited with "|" symbol, I am not allowed to use images since I have not enough reputation points)

**StartDate|EndDate|UID|Subject|EmpCode|EmpName|TestCode|TestName|TestMethod**

2014-02-02|2014-02-02|01|Plan name 1|E0001|Employee 1|TST01|Test Name 1|Test Method 1

2014-02-02|2014-02-02|01|Plan name 1|E0001|Employee 2|TST01|Test Name 1|Test Method 1

2014-02-02|2014-02-02|01|Plan name 1|E0001|Employee 3|TST01|Test Name 1|Test Method 1

2014-02-02|2014-02-02|01|Plan name 1|E0001|Employee 1|TST01|Test Name 2|Test Method 2

2014-02-02|2014-02-02|01|Plan name 1|E0001|Employee 2|TST01|Test Name 2|Test Method 2

2014-02-02|2014-02-02|01|Plan name 1|E0001|Employee 3|TST01|Test Name 2|Test Method 2

I want to make a report from this results that looks something similar to the following..

2014-02-02|2014-02-02|01|Plan name 1

TST01|Test Name 1|Test Method 1

TST01|Test Name 2|Test Method 2

E0001|Employee 1

E0001|Employee 2

E0001|Employee 3

How can I achieve this, any help?

Thanks,

JKV

Answer (score 1):

```
Create 3 groups
1. create with `plane name1` of use the combination of `2014-02-02|2014-02-02|01|Plan name 1` and place the 3 fields in group header1
2. Similar way group the second group as `TST01` or combination of `TST01|Test Name 1|Test Method 1` and place 3 fileds in groupheader2
3. now make another group 3 with `E0001`
4. Place the filed with `E0001` and `employee1 or 2 or 3` in detail section and refresh the report.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried this already, but the employee names will be repeated for every Test Names. I want the employee names only once because it will be same for every tests. So no need to repeat it.

Comment: Is there any way to suppress the Employee names if it is not the last record in a group?

Comment: you can use `onlastrecord` and if <<Employeename>>!=employee then true else false

Comment: Thank you for your response, It will hide the last record of entire data only, It is not what I am Looking for. I want to suppress all the data in details section if it is not last item of the CURRENT GROUP.